# Spring Security global method security location

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have defined  feature in main webappcontext config file. This file also contains  element which scans all packages except controller classes. A separate dispatcher-servlet context file scans controller package. If I apply method level security on controller methods that serve requests, it doesnt't work. It works only if I explicitly mention that element in dispatcher-servlet also.

From my earlier question on this forum, I understand that dispatcher-servlet context is the child of main webapp context. In that case, dispatcher-servlet should pickup that element from parent right?

Answer (score 2):

See [Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context) (emphasis mine). If you apply pointcuts to service layer you only need to set `<global-method-security>` in your app's security context.

> In a Spring web application, the application context which holds the
>   Spring MVC beans for the dispatcher servlet is often separate from the
>   main application context. It is often defined in a file called
>   myapp-servlet.xml, where “myapp” is the name assigned to the Spring
>   DispatcherServlet in web.xml. An application can have multiple
>   DispatcherServlets, each with its own isolated application context.
>   The beans in these “child” contexts are not visible to the rest of the
>   application. The “parent” application context is loaded by the
>   ContextLoaderListener you define in your web.xml and is visible to all
>   the child contexts. This parent context is usually where you define
>   your security configuration, including the 
>   element). As a result any security constraints applied to methods in
>   these web beans will not be enforced, since the beans cannot be seen
>   from the DispatcherServlet context. You need to either move the
>    declaration to the web context or moved the
>   beans you want secured into the main application context.
>
> **Generally we would recommend applying method security at the service
>   layer rather than on individual web controllers.**